# How to parse a JSON REST response - NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have the following URI which returns me a JSON response.
I tried to parse the response of get request and access to the `steps` array but it stops in the first step.

Here is my code:

```
 public  void getRoute() throws Exception {

      String urlToRead="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.43206,-81.38992&destination=Montreal&key=XXX";

      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(urlToRead);
      getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

      HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
      String json = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());


      JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(object.getJSONArray("routes"));
        }
   }
```

but it complains with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray
```

The maven is:

```
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Seems like you have missed jar file in the classpath

Comment: The error simply says you are missing the runtime dependency. You need to add `json.jar` in class path

Answer (score 0):

> `org/json/JSONArray`

You compiled the wrong library and/or imported the wrong class.

Replace

```
<groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
<artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
```

With

```
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20160810</version>
```